# adding error codes in yii login

Tags: yii

I am trying to add new custom error in my login, if user_status is '0' then it should give error, I am proceeding as follow :

UserIdentity.php

```
const ERROR_USERNAME_INACTIVE=68;
    public function authenticate()
    {
        $user = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$this->username));


        if ($user===null)
        {
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        }
        else if ($user->password !== md5($this->password))
        {
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        }
        else if($user->user_status !='1')
        {
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INACTIVE;
        }
        else 
        {
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
            $this->_id = $user->id;
        }
        return !$this->errorCode;
    }
```

In login.php

```
case UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE:
                    Yii::app()->user->login($identity);
                    break;
                case UserIdentity::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID:
                    $this->addError('username','No Such user is associated with us .');
                    break;
                case UserIdentity::ERROR_USERNAME_INACTIVE:
                    $this->addError('user_status','Sorry, this user is not activated yet');
                default: // UserIdentity::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID

                    $this->addError('password','Password is incorrect.');
                    break;
```

Now I am getting problem that when the user_Status is !=1 then it is giving the error correctly but also giving, password incorrect while the password is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add a `break` to the last case statement. Without a break the `default` will be executed.

```
...
    break;
case UserIdentity::ERROR_USERNAME_INACTIVE:
    $this->addError('user_status','Sorry, this user is not activated yet');
    break;
default: // UserIdentity::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was making a silly mistake, after switch case, i forget to put break statement so the next default statement was also executing.

```
 case UserIdentity::ERROR_USERNAME_INACTIVE:
             $this->addError('user_status','Sorry, this user is not activated yet');
             **break;**
                default: // UserIdentity::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID

                    $this->addError('password','Password is incorrect.');
                    break;
```